# When 2 witnesses are required to verify something, can one or both of them witness this using Skype?

Tags: technology, edim-witnesses

Examples of when you need 2 witnesses testifying an event:

- groom's "purchase" / acceptance of the terms of the ketuvah
- witnessing kiddushin (groom giving bride a ring)

If two witnesses watch this event via video camera, Skype, etc. and are neither physically at the event nor is each witness in the same place as the other, is their observance acceptable testimony. Or must they be physically present at the event?

The 2 items listed are examples, The question is meant to be a general rule, unless certain types of witnessing have different conditions. If so, please state why.

Comment: Have you ever seen those movies where the burglars put the surveillance system on a loop and the guards never realize?

Comment: @DoubleAA "Speed"

Comment: @DoubleAA or Oceans 11. Regardless, doesn't the gemara talk about a case where the witness saw the action take place through a mirror or something similar? There is a distinction made between witness to prove an action happened and witnesses to "establish an act." Halachically, the edim at a wedding are in the latter category, and their participation is rabbinically mandatory as a prerequisite for the transaction to actually take place. Another example of this is kiddush hachodesh and beit din, where you still need two separate edim even though all of B"D saw the new moon.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Edim for Kiddush Hachodesh is an example of testimony of a past event. However, I think there was a requirement that the witnesses specifically appear before Sanhedrin. With current technology, if Sanhedrin and Bet Hamikdash existed, could the head of Sanhedrin ask questions via chat? Seems that this may be acceptable.

Comment: "Seems that this may be acceptable." On what basis? How is this any different than sending a prerecorded video which would be eidus min haksav, which is not admissible in beis din? We require physical presence for a reason, and even allow someone to be mechallel shabbos for kiddush hachodesh in order to be there in person. The only acceptable substitute is if there was a beis din by the eid, who then appointed a shaliach to testify ***to the result of the other beis din*** in front of the Sanhedrin.

Comment: Heck, if we allow someone "skypeing" as valid eidus, how is live video of an event any different than recorded video? Why do we need eidim at all? we already have a videographer!

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky valid point u made. My premise is that Kiddush Hachodesh testifies to a past event. OK, so the witness appears before Bet Din to answer questions. Technically, what's the difference if he's asked personally or on the phone or chat conference? You get the same info and can make the same conclusions.

Comment: Because the requirement isn't just for the information (otherwise edus min haksav would be acceptable). The presence of the eid in court is an a priori requirement to the validity of the ruling of B"D. If the eid isn't present, then halachically we can't validly issue a judgment.

Comment: Since he is not present i would call this "עד מפי עד" which is valid only to  allow an Iguna to marry.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky If I'm understanding you correctly, in all cases, he must be physically present at a "court" to testify, and this is needed in ALL cases of edut. This implies that presence on a phone or via a camera does not work. If this is a correct assumption and you can support with some source, please post as an answer. Otherwise, we would just be rehashing the premise of my question, i.e. camera / web presence = physical presence.

Comment: @Emilios1995 See ^^^^. If you can cite a source to demonstrate that camera or web presence <> physical presence, that makes an answer.

Comment: I saw a writeup on this question in a (Hebrew) pamphlet on internet halacha. I'll see if I can find the article

Answer (score 1):

I found this article: [http://www.din.org.il/2015/01/18/עדות-באמצעות-סקייפ/](http://www.din.org.il/2015/01/18/%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A4/)

Which confirms the view of @IsaacKotlicky regarding testimony for a wedding or divorce i.e. since this testimony is עדות  לקיומי the witnesses have to be in the place, although maybe it depends on the machloket of עדות עפ"י אומדנא.

However if the case requires Edut just as a testimony of a past event, see (אגרות משה סימן מז) where he allows "chalav akum" in places where the company under the gov's supervision, based on the claim that clear knowledge = watching the event.